# remaining elements between url's

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to write an website where some elements maintains between url's. Im not sure what way is the best approach to this. Ideally the clicked elements exists in both urls (partials?) but isn't reloaded but the same element remains after changing url.

I figure that nested views won't work entirely since what I'd like to do is to access the same element from the previous view after changing the url.

thanks!

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tutoring.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the question is too vague for SO, but I'd like to question why you are looking to have the same element persist across pages.  Angular is designed with SPA (single-page applications) in mind.  Thus, if your requirement is strongest to keep the same html element on the screen after some other action, consider designing your application as one single page, and change everything on the screen around that special div.

Comment: I have a design that is based on elements staying in place between views. For example, if you click a title and go to the url **#the-article** the title is in the same position as on, say, **#home**. My main question is if Angular is the right tool for this, and if so, how to get about creating elements that stay between views. It seems like all scopes in Angular are naturally very compartmentalised and hiearchially structured, so I can't see an easy way to do this in Angular.